# Deleted sql statement still called by symfony cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm using Symfony 2.7

Instead of using doctrine, i've build a service which do all raw sql statement and is called RawSQLManager.

Randomly, when i pull the same URL multiple time, i've a critical error in my dev.log file. I don't understand how it can be possible.

At the beginning of my project i've build this function :

```
public function getFolderInfo($id_folder)
{

    $sql = 'SELECT zs.ID, zs.Nom, zs.Principale, zs.Archive, zs.DateHeureModification
        FROM Zones_Stockages zs
        WHERE zs.ID = :id_folder;';

    $params['id_folder'] = $id_folder;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);

    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Now, i don't use this function, she's deleted and no one use this function in my whole project.

But here my log :

```
[2016-01-05 10:16:09] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.Principale AS Principale_1, t0.Archive AS Archive_2, t0.Nom AS Nom_3, t0.DateHeureModification AS DateHeureModification_4, t0.ID AS ID_5, t0.Abonnements_ID AS Abonnements_ID_6 FROM Zones_Stockages t0 WHERE t0.ID = ? ["7385"] []
```

as you can see, that's the <strike>exact same statement</strike> and nowhere in my project there is a similar statement.

**[EDIT]** : There is no Abonnements_ID in my initial statement.

I've cleared my cache with the following :

```
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

even delete my cache folder. This statement still be called.

And this weird call is called at every request i do on the server and sometimes is followed by a critical error onto my Abonnements Entity, but i don't understand what does this have to do with the previous call and how to start debugging what's wrong with this Entity.

```
[2016-01-05 10:16:09] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: rename(C:\wamp\www\app\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntityAbonnements.php.568b89d923b5a9.13683491,C:\wamp\www\app\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntityAbonnements.php): " at C:\wamp\www\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator.php line 306 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Warning: rename(C:\\wamp\\www\\app\\cache\\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\\__CG__AppBundleEntityAbonnements.php.568b89d923b5a9.13683491,C:\\wamp\\www\\app\\cache\\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\\__CG__AppBundleEntityAbonnements.php):  at C:\\wamp\\www\\vendor\\doctrine\\common\\lib\\Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\ProxyGenerator.php:306)"} []
```

So two issues in a row :

1. A call to a ghost statement.
2. A critical error that append randomly on the same url, with same parameters.

What did i miss please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the "ghost statement", the reason can only be: the code is somehow still present in the application ... or some cache is in place (for example Opcache or something like that in the web server).

About the "critical error", the line of code that triggers it is `rename($tmpFileName, $fileName);` inside the code that creates Doctrine proxies for entities. Since this is just a file rename, this could be a permission issue in your cache directory.

Comment: You where right. My bad. It was 'hide' behind the only one getRepository(). what a dump question. sorry and thank you to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Doctrine's proxy class generation code doesn't handle concurrent requests very well. It works on Unix-like systems, but not on Windows, where you can't just rename over a file that is open.

See configuration of the doctrine bundle. You'll most like have auto_generate_proxy_classes set to "%kernel.debug%" (this is the default setting in symfony standard edition).

Try changing auto_generate_proxy_classes to false. You'll now have to manually clear the cache if you change your entities, but that error should be gone.